# excel real time refresh of filter

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, updates

In my Pivot Table in excel, I have a field List about the due date of some reports.

For example, 10/5/2016

My problem is, every day I have to choose the date so that I can see the report code, I don't want it to be this. What I want is, everyday I open the excel, the filter will automatically change from 10/5/2016 to 11/5/2016.

What function / VBA should I use?

Helps

Comment: record a macro whilst changing your date filter, then use that code inside `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` to run when ever you open the file, and change the filter range to be todays date `Date()` . Have a play then update your question with the code if you get stuck.

Comment: look at question such as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406979/what-is-a-good-way-to-autorun-macros-upon-open

Comment: record a macro, you mean record it from changing 10/5/2016 to 11/5/2016? How about when it comes to 12/5/2016?

Comment: read my first comment again

Comment: Do you mean, 1) record a macro, 2) add some code in that macro about      Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Comment: If It is correct, what should I do while recording? Just Pull down the date filter and do nothing? Sorry for the trouble, I am not familiar with this.

Comment: Unless I am missing something here, simple Excel formula would resolve this. Just type =NOW() and press Enter in the cell for which you need to chose the date. Excel will update automatically. If it does not update current date than you may have formula calculation set to Manual. If so, just press F11 from Excel to re-calculate the entire workbook ...Manual.

Comment: But I have to change to filter list so that I can see the report code. the filter list in pivot table is not allow to use any function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a VBA solution, add the following to the `ThisWorkbook` code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim tDay As Date, pf As PivotField
tDay = Date

    Set pf = Sheets("name of worksheet").PivotTables("pivot table name").PivotFields("insert the name of your filter here")

    pf.ClearAllFilters
    pf.CurrentPage = tDay

End Sub
```

Change the sheet name, pivot table name and the name of the filter.

If you need to do more VBA manipulation of pivot tables I suggest reading the following http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables.

Comment: Tim, I want to ask one more thing. How about I want to update it with 2 days? If I write pf.CurrentPage = tDay, pf.CurrentPage = tDay + 1, It will only show the report no of tDay + 1, Is there any method to show all 2 days?